# Copy childs' attribute and value to parent using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have something like this

```
<div>
 <span id="1"></span>
</div>
<div>
 <span id="2"></span>
</div>
<div>
 <span id="3"></span>
</div>
```

I need the id of each span to be put in to its parent div

result should be something like this

```
<div id="1">
 <span></span>
</div>
<div id="2">
 <span></span>
</div>
<div id="3">
 <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: I do hope you're planning to remove that ID from the child afterwards....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `.attr()`'s receiver function to accomplish your task,

```
$('div').attr('id',function(){
 return $(this).children('span').attr('id');
}).children('span').removeAttr('id');
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Zt5S2/)

Comment: @user3264864 please note that while this code is indeed functionally correct, it's pretty inefficient.  Learn how to perform DOM manipulation properly and don't use jQuery for trivial operations that are better done without it.

Answer (score 2):

Try below

```
$("div span").each(function(){
   $(this).parent().attr("id",$(this).attr("id"));
   $(this).removeAttr('id');
});
```

Comment: well, it's better than the accepted answer, but still inefficient (five jQuery calls inside the loop)

Answer (score 1):

Fastest solution, using direct DOM manipulation and avoiding using jQuery within the loop:  Also, starting with the spans themselves instead of the divs makes it easier to work with the parent.

```
$('span[id]').each(function() {  // only consider spans with an ID
    var id = this.id;            // get the original ID
    this.id = null;              // remove it from the span
    this.parentNode.id = id;     // and give it to its parent
});
```

This *could* strictly be one line shorter (`this.parentNode.id = this.id; this.id = null`) but as written it ensures that the ID is *never* on two elements at once.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('div').each(function(item){ // loop all divs
    var $span =  $($(this).children('span')); // find the "span" tag inside "div", "this" in this context is "div" tag
    $(this).attr('id', $span.attr('id')); // update id for "div" tag
    $span.removeAttr('id'); // remove id of "span" tag
});
```

Comment: @Alnitak: do you mean my `$span`?

Comment: I mean every single use of `$(...)` inside the loop

Comment: I think it would be more helpful for the OP and other visitors in the future, whenn you add some explainations for your intension.

Comment: @Alnitak My comment belongs to the answer of Stiger, not for you :-)